# how to use ajax in magento backend

Tags: magento

why ajax call from magento backend(from .phtml) redirects to magento dashboard despite of sending form key properly with form? please help.

in ajax call :

```
var dataRecord = j('#newForm').serialize(); 
    var url = "<?php echo $this->getUrl('*/*/addNewColumn') ?>";

    j.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: url,
    data: {data1: dataRecord}
    })
    .done(function( msg ) {
        alert(msg);
    });
```

Comment: If I understand you correctly, that you show JS code but you talk about a response from controller. Could you show code from the method `addNewColumnAction`?

Comment: public function addNewColumnAction(){
  
  $data = Mage::app()->getRequest()->getParam('data1');
         var_dump($data); 


 }

Comment: I'm not sure that you call this action. Could you add wrong code after your `var_dump` e.g. `var_dump($data);  dd();`. If you will be redirected to dashboard then it will mean that you call action by wrong route

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It worked when i sent the form_key in 'data' of ajax call.

```
var dataRecord = jQuery('#newForm').serialize(); 
var url = "<?php echo $this->getUrl('*/*/addNewColumn') ?>";
<?php $k = Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getFormKey(); ?>

jQuery.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: url,
data: {data1: dataRecord,form_key:'<?php echo $k ?>'}
})
.done(function( msg ) {
    alert(msg);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Below are the code for ajax in admin panel.

```
jQuery(".btn_save_email").click(function(){
        var data1val = jQuery('.data1val').val();
        var data2val = jQuery('.data2val').val();
        url = '<?php echo $this->getUrl('moduleName/adminhtml_controllerName/functionName') ?>';             
        new Ajax.Request(url, {
        parameters: {isAjax: 1, method: 'POST',data1:data1val,data2:data2val},
        onSuccess: function(transport) {
           jQuery('.class').html(transport['responseText']);
        }
       }); 
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

For call Ajax or js in a block file use the following code

you can create setAfterElementHtml of $fieldset->addField() function and define your jquery their like

```
$addfieldset->setAfterElementHtml('
                        <script>
                        require([\'jquery\'], function($){
                         $("#flashsale_deal_discount_type").on("change", function () {
                            if($("#elements").val() == "percent"){
                               $(this).addClass("activePageGroups")
                               var actionURl = ''; // put url here
                                $.ajax({
                                    url: actionURl,
                                    type: 'post',
                                    dataType: 'json',
                
                                    /** @param {Object} response */
                                    success: function (response) {
                                        self.showLabels(response);
                                    },
                
                                    /** set empty array if error occurs */
                                    error: function (err) {
                                        console.log('file url fetching error: '+err);
                                    }
                                });

                            }
                            else{
                                $(this)..removeClass("validate-digits validate-digits-range digits-range-1-100");
                            }
                            });
                        });
                        </script>
                    ');
```

For call Ajax in admin, phtml file us the following code

```
<script>
    require([
            'jquery',
        ], function($) {
            //<![CDATA[
                 const serviceUrl = customer.isLoggedIn()
                ? urlBuilder.createUrl('/carts/mine/save-source-data', {}) : '';
            if (serviceUrl) {
                $.ajax({
                    url: urlFormatter.build(serviceUrl),
                    data: JSON.stringify(data),
                    global: false,
                    contentType: 'application/json',
                    type: 'POST',
                    async: true
                }).done(
                    function (response) {
                        console.log("Success in saving stock transfer data");
                        console.log(response);
                    }
                ).fail(
                    function (response) {
                        console.log("Error in saving stock transfer data");
                        console.log(response);
                    }
                );
            }
            //]]>
        }
    ); </script>
```